# Can we use an AppIntent to trigger background fetching?

Tags: ios, sirishortcuts, appintents

Our goal is to build an iPad app which fetches data every 5 minutes, without the app ever being opened. (The app is a backup for emergency use.) Background tasks won't work if the app is very rarely opened. One idea is to expose an `AppIntent` and then to use the Shortcuts app and setup "Automations". Then we setup an Automation to trigger the `AppIntent`.

I believe that by setting [openAppWhenRun](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appintents/appintent/openappwhenrun-3u9y8) to false, we can create an `AppIntent` which can be run without the app being opened, or even the screen being on.

My question is, can we perform HTTP requests and so on from a non interactive `AppIntent` invocation that is triggered by a Shortcuts Automation?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes, this is possible. I tested it today and was able to make network requests and save files all inside an `AppIntent` invocation without user interaction even while the device was off.